# Display the product image in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: woocommerce

On Woocommerce, I have changed `$show_image` variable to **`true`** in email order details php template file, but I am still unable to get the image displayed in email notifications:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
            'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
            'show_image'    => true,
            'image_size'    => array( 100, 100 ),
            'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
            'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
        ) );
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
        $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

        if ( $totals ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                $i++;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Message:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I need to add link as well to the product image.Once the user click on the image it should redirect to the particular page.

Changed the message from false to true still the image is not displayed in the site.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To display the image in Email notifications**, revert back your changes to original template and use instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'custom_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );
function custom_email_order_items_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_image'] = true;

    return $args;
}
```

To add the product link to **the image** and to **the item name** *(optionally)* you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', 'add_email_order_item_permalink', 10, 2 ); // Product image
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_email_order_item_permalink', 10, 2 ); // Product name
function add_email_order_item_permalink( $output_html, $item, $bool = false ) {
    // Only email notifications
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        return $output_html;

    $product   = $item->get_product();

    return '<a href="'.esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ).'">' . $output_html . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Thumbnail size change:**

You can also manipulate the thumbnail size in this hook which is by default 32 x 32 pixels using under `$args['show_image'] = true;` adding this line:

```
$args['image_size'] = array( 48, 48 );
```

Tested and works too.

Comment: i am not getting image in email hyperlink is working fine but image is not working

Comment: Added how i am getting it in email it is displaying gap but not getting the image

Comment: Total code should be added in functions.php file or else the code from add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', 'add_email_order_item_permalink', 10, 2 ); // Product image
 this line to added in functions.php file

Comment: Actually i have copied all the code in function.php file itself but still i am unable to see the product image in email.I have reverted my code back in email template as well but still not able to see image

Comment: I had the same issue with pictures showing up as broken images in my emails. I tried a different email account and it turns out that it had to do with those settings, not with the code. I had html emails enabled for the first email account I tried, but still. Anyway, maybe this helps someone who encounters this problem.