# WooCommerce: show image and link of purchased products in customer email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach

When a customer has bought an item, `WooCommerce` automatically sends an email on order status 'complete'.  I'm trying to add an image and a link of the purchased product to this email template. The email template is stored as the file `customer-completed-order.php`.

However, when the test email arrives in my email account, it shows a broken image. I'm not sure what to query to get the permalink for the purchased products, either. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details) post, which states many (all?) properties for the order object, but not what I'm looking for (I think).

This is the code from my email template:

```
 <?php
    $order = $order->get_id();
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
            echo $product->get_image();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of editing the template file you could use [Display the product image in Woocommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608751/display-the-product-image-in-woocommerce-email-notifications/53609183#53609183)

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome! I will try it.